# How does one go about laying image colors under text?

Tags: css, html, image, image-processing, canvas

[image]

What's the best way to make the text color take the color according to its appropriate position in a corresponding image file? Additionally, some text are some parts one color, some parts other, so it looks smooth.

Twitter Data did this, where the text were all tweets mentioning Prince.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing).

Through canvas2d API it's quite easy to manage :

The [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property offers quite a wide list of different compositing modes.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
canvas.width = this.width;
canvas.height = this.height;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '8px sans-serif';

for(var i=0; i<300; i++){ // fill some dummy text
  let txt = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amer '.repeat(20).substring(~~(Math.random()*27));
  ctx.fillText(txt, 0, 7*i)
  }
// at this moment our canvas only has pixels where text is filled.
// 'source-atop' will place new pixels only where there already were pixels
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
}
img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Note that for text, this can also be achieved only with CSS in modern browsers, thanks to the [`background-clip: text;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) property :

```js
text.textContent = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amer '.repeat(2000);
```

```css
#text{
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg);
  /* pre-fixed (both FF and chrome)*/
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  /* Standards */
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  
  width: 800px;
  height: 1164px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 8px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish this task with `mix-blend-mode: difference;`.

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url(https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.el,
.el2,
.el3 {
  padding: 20px;
}

.el {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.el2 {
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.el3 {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bg">
    <div class="el">directly opposite image color. directly opposite image color. directly opposite image color.</div>
    <div class="el2">one variant. one variant. one variant. one variant. one variant. one variant. one variant.</div>
    <div class="el3">another variant. another variant. another variant. another variant. another variant.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```